# Global variables in C are static or not?

Tags: c, static, global-variables, extern

Are global variables in C `static` or `extern` by default?
If global variables are by default `static` then it means that we would be able to access them in a single file, but we can use global variables in different files as well.
Does this imply that they have `extern` storage by default?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you do not specify a storage class (that is, the `extern` or `static` keywords), then by default global variables have external linkage.  From the C99 standard:

> **§6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers**
>
> 3)    If the declaration of a file scope identifier for an object or a function contains the storage-class specifier `static`, the identifier has internal linkage.
>
> 5)    If the declaration of an identifier for a function has no storage-class specifier, its linkage is determined exactly as if it were declared with the storage-class specifier `extern`. If the declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and no storage-class specifier, its linkage is external.

So even if you don't specify the `extern` keyword, globals can still be accessed by other source files (so-called *translation units*), because they can still have an `extern` declaration for the same variable.  If you use the `static` keyword to specify internal linkage, then even in the presence of an `extern` declaration for the same variable name in another source file, it will refer to a different variable.

Comment: also relevant: section 6.9.2, which describes tentative definitions; §4 of that section shows explicitly how multiple definitions of file-scope variables interact

Comment: @Mishthi: Do you mean a variable that is both static and extern? I'm afraid that's not possible.

Comment: @Mishthi: `static extern varx` is undefined behavior.  A variable cannot be both `static` and `extern`, it has to be one or the other.

Comment: Is this also true in C++? Or just C?

Comment: @SSHThis: Yes, the same is true in C++.  See C++03 §3.5 [basic.link].

Comment: Actually, `static extern varx;` is not undefined behaviour; it is a constraint violation.  C11 [§6.7.1 Storage classes ¶2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.1p2): _At most, one storage-class specifier may be given in the declaration specifiers in a declaration, except that `_Thread_local` may appear with `static` or `extern`._ . There's also a problem with 'implicit int' type in the attempted declaration — that's not been legal in standard C in the current millennium (it was outlawed by C99, though some compilers still allow it unless prodded into rejecting it).

Answer (score 7):

In C, a global variable which doesn't have an initializer or any storage class specifiers is a tentative definition of a variable with *static storage duration* and *external linkage*.

In a translation unit all tentative definitions and up to one non-tentative definition (e.g. from a declaration with an initializer) are collapsed into a single definition for a variable. Although it's not allowed to have a definition of the same variable in multiple translation units it is a common extension to allow "common" variables, i.e. tentative definitions of the same variable in multiple translation units.

Answer (score 4):

Global variables in C are by default extern.. (i.e) they have external linkage..

To restrict the external linkage, 'static' storage class specifier can be used for the global variable.. if static specifier is used, then the variable has file scope.. You cannot link it in an other file using the 'extern' keyword..

Specifying 'static' depends on your usage of the program..