# Understanding static storage class in C

Tags: c

`static` is the default storage class for global variables. The two variables below (`Count` and `Road`) both have `static` storage class.

```
static int Count;
int Road;
int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", Road);
    return 0;
}
```

My question is: if by default global variables are `static` (which means we are limiting the scope of that global variable to that particular `.c` file) then how can we `extern` those variables in another file?

This question might be very basic to many of you but I am really confused and want to learn the correct details.

Comment: read( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271902/static-vs-global && http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239834/global-variable-in-c-are-static-or-not ) :)

Comment: Your first sentence is false.  A variable declared `static` at file scope is *not* a global variable.

Comment: Your source is wrong. Variables and functions declared at the file scope have `extern` storage class by default (although that gives them static *duration*). The `static` keyword gives them static storage class.

Comment: @hobbs: An object declared at file scope as external *linkage* and static *storage duration*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the formal C terminology specifiers like `extern`, `static`, `register` etc. are called *storage-class* specifiers, but the actual object properties these specifiers control are called *storage duration* and *linkage*.

In your question you seem to be mixing these two unrelated concepts: *storage duration* and *linkage*. It is actually *linkage* that describes external visibility of the object.

All variables defined in file scope have static storage duration (regardless of whether you used the keyword `static` in the declaration). This simply means that they live forever, but it does not say anything about their external visibility. Meanwhile, variables defined with keyword `static` have internal linkage, while variables defined without any keywords or with keyword `extern` have external linkage.

In your example variable `Road` has static storage duration and *external* linkage, which is why you can access it directly from other translation units. Variable `Count` has static storage duration and *internal* linkage, which is why you can't access it directly from other translation units.

If you declare a variable without a storage class specifier (like `Road` in your example), it will be treated as so called *tentative definition* and finally resolve (in your example) to a variable with static storage duration and *external* linkage. So, from that point of view it is right to say that the default (implied) storage class specifier for file scope variables is actually `extern`, not `static`.

Comment: If C "does not have such term as 'storage class'" this answer cannot be correct.

Comment: @hobbs: Sorry for my confusion. Your comment under the original question is correct, in a sense that variables declared without storage class specifier behave as if they vere declared with `extern` storage class specifier (of course, things get a bit more complicated when we take into account tentative definitions, but that's a different story).

Answer (score 7):

The variable `Count` is only accessible by name within this one source file because of the `static` that precedes it.  Formally, it is said to have *internal linkage* (see ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.2.2 Linkages of Identifiers).

The variable `Road` could be accessed from other source files if those files included the equivalent of `extern int Road;` as one of the statements.  Formally, it is said to have *external linkage*.

Generally, most people would call `Count` a static variable and `Road` a global variable.

See also [What are `extern` variables in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c/)

Comment: so what is the default storage class for global variables then?

Comment: 'Global variable' variable is not a term defined in Standard C.  However, variables with external linkage are what most people think of as global variables, so their storage class is `extern`.