# Get address of a static struct member from another header file

Tags: c, struct

I am having trouble putting together some code in which I wish to have the following:

- Have a header file `myHeader.h` in which I create a type `struct myStruct` with members `int number1`, `int number2` and `int number3`. This file would also contain a "getter" prototype for getting the address of each of the members in a `struct` instance.
- A translation unit (`file.c`) in which I declare a *static* instance of `struct myStruct`, i.e. `static struct myStruct myStructInstance`. This translation unit defines the "getter" functions (I will illustrate with a code example at the end of the post).
- Another header file `anotherHeader.h` in which I wish to - now this is a tricky bit that's causing problems for me - get the addresses of each of the members of a static structure and use them for something.

Here's an example to show what I am talking about.

**myHeader.h**

```
struct myStruct{
    int number1;
    int number2;
    int number3;
};

int* get_number1(void);
int* get_number2(void);
int* get_number3(void);
```

**file.c**

```
#include <myHeader.h>

static struct myStruct myStructInstance = {
        .number1 = 0,
        .number2 = 0,
        .number3 = 0
};

int* get_number1(void){
    struct myStruct* ptr_myStructInstance = &(myStructInstance);
    int* number1Address = &(ptr_myStructInstance->number1);
    return number1Address;
}

int* get_number2(void){
    struct myStruct* ptr_myStructInstance = &(myStructInstance);
    int* number2Address = &(ptr_pfcVariables->number2);
    return number2Address;
}

int* get_number3(void){
    struct myStruct* ptr_myStructInstance = &(myStructInstance);
    int* number3Address = &(ptr_myStructInstance->number3);
    return number3Address;
}
```

**anotherHeader.h**

```
#include <myHeader.h>

int* pNumber1 = get_number1();

int* pNumber2 = get_number2();

int* pNumber3 = get_number3();
```

The problem is that the code shown above throws "initializer element is not constant" error in `anotherHeader.h`. I've read a few answers as to why we cannot use non-constant expressions when initializing variables with static storage duration, however I do not understand how this relates to my code.

Comment: Why not simply do e.g. `return &myStructInstance.number1`?

Comment: As for your `anotherHeader.h`, why do you *define* the variables in the header? That means the header file can't be included in multiple source files.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg No particular reason - in fact, that's what I had originally. It wasn't working either way, and I just pasted whatever code there is right now.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg And yes, you are absolutely correct about defining the variables in the header - thank you for pointing this our for me!

Comment: It would be interesting to know what you're actually trying to accomplish. Everything about this has a bad [smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) to it.

Comment: Something like `int* pNumber1 = get_number1();` does **not** even belong into a header (well, inside an `inline` function, but that is a different subject)!

Comment: And `static` is not the same as _static storage duration_.

Comment: Thank you for your comments everyone. @user3386109 In short, this is for an embedded system application -  I am trying to program a linked list for a DMA controller and wanted to move linked list initialization into it's own header. The `static struct` definition is in the DMA configuration file - and I just didn't want to clutter it with linked list initialization. Do you think there are any fundamental mistakes that I made in doing so?

Comment: @agrus Headers are for (extern) declarations, data type definitions, and macros. Initializations (code) and global variables do not belong into a header.

Comment: @PSkocik That makes sense - thank you for clarifying this for me!

Comment: My crystal ball shows a setter: `set_numbers(int num1, int num2, int num3)`. Without knowing all the details, I can't do better than that.

Comment: @agrus Forget the accessors and static. You want just one `struct myStruct myStructInstance = {/*the values*/};` in a c file, `extern struct myStruct myStructInstance;` in a header, and that's absolutely it. 2 lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

> I've read a few answers as to why we cannot use non-constant expressions when initializing variables with static storage duration, however I do not understand how this relates to my code.

A function call is a non-constant expression.

```
int* pNumber1 = get_number1();
```

The above code is trying to initialize a global variable with a non-constant expression.

Comment: So this rule also applied to global variables, not just static ones?

Comment: Global variables have static storage duration.

Comment: @jxh: `static` is not the same as _static storage duration_.

Comment: Related, but not quite a dup: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17182648/315052

Comment: Thank you for your comments and suggestions. I will take a look at what the difference is. @jxh Could you please suggest a better way to go about this piece of code? I am trying to set up a linked list in a separate header, and it needs access to the addresses of a `static struct` members in order to know where to store the information. Thank you!

Comment: Call a function to set up the linked list.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't call code in the global scope.

However, you could easily accomplish the same thing as what you appear to be trying to do by simply extending **myHeader.h** with:

```
extern int *pNumber1, *pNumber2, *pNumber3;
```

and then allocating and initializing these in **file.c** with:

```
int *pNumber1 =  &myStructInstance.number1,
    *pNumber2 =  &myStructInstance.number2,
    *pNumber3 =  &myStructInstance.number3;
```

Comment: Without further information, all this looks like a bad idea and likely some XY-problem.

Comment: I wanted to move away from sharing variables using `extern` - hence the (perhaps unnecessary) complexity in my code.