# Are global variables extern by default or is it equivalent to declaring variable with extern in global?

Tags: c++, c, static, global, extern

I have gone through following two questions:

[static and extern global variables in C and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055802/static-and-extern-global-variables-in-c-and-c)

[global variable in C are static or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239834/global-variable-in-c-are-static-or-not)

Both questions says the two things in different way.

Question 1's Answer:

> Global variables are not extern nor static by default on C and C++.

Question 2's Answer:

> If you do not specify a storage class (that is, the extern or static keywords), then by default global variables have external linkage

I need to know the following:

1. Are global variables `extern` by default in linkage (or) is it equivalent to declaring variables by specifying `extern` storage class?
2. Are global variables `static` by default in scope (or) is it equivalent to declaring variables by specifying `static` storage class?
3. Is there any difference with `C` or `C++`? Can anyone please clarify?

Comment: Answers: 1) Yes, 2) No, 3) No

Answer (score 14):

> is global variables are `extern` by default in linkage (or) it is equivalent to declaring variable by specifying `extern` storage class?

The default storage duration, scope and linkage of variables declared outside any block, at the outer most level, have `static` storage duration, *file* scope and `external` linkage. C11 standard says that:

#### 6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers (p4):

> [...] If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier appears outside of any block or list of parameters, **the identifier has *file scope***, which terminates at the end of the translation unit. [...]

#### 6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers (p5):

> [...] If the declaration of an identifier for an object has file scope and no storage-class specifier, its linkage is `external`.

#### 6.2.4 Storage durations of objects (p3):

> An object whose identifier is declared without the storage-class specifier
> `_Thread_local`, and either with *external* or *internal* linkage or with the storage-class specifier `static`, has *static storage duration*.

So, if `x` is global

```
int x;
```

then its storage duration, scope and linkage is equivalent to `x` in

```
extern int x;
```

> is global variables are `static` by default in scope (or) it is equivalent to declaring variable by specifying `static` storage class?

No. As I stated above that its duration is `static` and it has *file* scope.

> If there is any c or c++ difference please clarify?

No difference. Rule is same in both languages.

Comment: From the way this reads, your third section (6.2.4) reads as though the statement `int x;` is equivalent to `extern int x;`.  This will result in linkage error(s) as `int x;` generates the symbol with the correct space while `extern int x;` only produces a reference to a symbol defined elsewhere.

Comment: You're missing a third important distinction: declaration vs. definition.  `extern int i;` is not a definition, so `i` must be defined elsewhere.  `int i;` or `extern int i = 42;` are definitions, and `i` may not be defined elsewhere.

Comment: @Mark; There was some error in previous answer. Corrected that. See the revision history.

Answer (score 7):

> is global variables are extern by default in linkage (or) it is equivalent to declaring variable by specifying extern storage class?

Unless otherwise specified, they have external linkage (except in C++, where they have internal linkage if they're constant).

The first answer you link to is saying that it's not equivalent to declaring it `extern` (which makes it a pure declaration, not a definition); not that it doesn't have external linkage.

> is global variables are static by default in scope (or) it is equivalent to declaring variable by specifying static storage class?

In C++, they have internal linkage (as if declared `static`) if they are constant, external linkage otherwise. In C, they always have external linkage.

> If there is any c or c++ difference please clarify?

As mentioned above, the default is always external linkage in C, while in C++ it's internal for constant variables.

Answer (score 0):

Verified by using `gcc version9.3.0`:

Global variables are extern by default.