# Relation between static keyword and compilation time/runtime

Tags: c

In C, why do we use the static keyword for variables or functions with internal linkage (restricted to translation unit)? I thought that static vs dynamic refers to something happening at compilation time vs runtime. So in this context, why it is called static?

Comment: It's a historical holdover, going [all the way back to C](https://www.javatpoint.com/static-in-c#:~:text=Static%20is%20a%20keyword%20used,variable%20is%20throughout%20the%20program.).

Comment: The `static` keyword does multiple things and some different things in different places because C was developed by different people tinkering with it in different ways. The results were a bit disorganized in how declarations behaved, and the C standard committee sought to codify that as best it could. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63448619/298225) touches on it.

Comment: "Static vs dynamic" in a general sense is just buzzwords. There's not one single meaning to "static" and "dynamic" in this context, the words by themselves mean nothing.

Comment: I think `static` was originally only used to declare local variables within a function, giving them persistent storage that was shared across all invocations of that function.  Later, when they wanted a way to restrict the scope of top-level entities in a file, then reused the existing keyword rather than introduce a new one.

Comment: ... and perhaps the (somewhat contorted) thought process considered that identifiers with internal linkage could be *linked* "statically", as opposed to in a separate linker pass over potentially multiple TUs.

Comment: One useful document is Dennis RItchie's 1993 CACM article [The Development of the C Language](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html).  However, it only mentions 'static' 4 times, and there is no detailed discussion of what it means.